# Is there any way to stop a GET method form from sending empty variables?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using the following form as part of an Advanced Search page on my WordPress install.

```
<form action="/advanced-search/" method="get">
```

The form is working correctly, but producing URLs like:

`/advanced-search/page/3/?act=s&f=cichlidae&g&s&c&r&tmin&tmax&hmin&hmax&pHmin&pHmax&cmin&cmax&sF&sM&aL&aD&aH`

Is there any way to stop the form from sending those empty variables? In the above example only `f` was searched for (value `cichlidae`). As such I'd prefer it to produce a URL like this:

`/advanced-search/?act=s&f=cichlidae` (plus the `/page/3/` if necessary).

I can't use `$_POST` because I can't get the WordPress `paged` variable to work with `$_POST` values.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use jQuery's [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to collect all the form values in a string?

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   var string = $(this).serialize();
   window.location.href = '/advanced-search/'+string;
});
```

It loops through all of your form elements, collects their values and converts it into a readable string format for use in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Not built-in to a form, no - if the field exists, it'll be sent.

You could use Javascript to submit the form instead, and thus omit empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way (without JavaScript that is). If there was, this would be browser-specific, since it's the browser that decides what to do with the form data.

Also, this:

```
foo.php?a=
```

...and this:

```
foo.php
```

...is semantically different. In the former, `a` is passed with an empty string (`""`) while the in latter, `a` is not passed at all (`null`).

Also, Wordpress is correct here, since the form is a search form, thus it is *retrieving* data and should use `GET`; and not *creating* data as `POST` should do.

A way to change this (without JavaScript) is to use a gateway script that removes empty parameters from the URL and redirect.

Per example:

```
$newGET = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($value !== '') $newGET[$key] = $value;
}

header('Location: some/url?'.http_build_query($newGET));
exit;
```